# Adding a save button to the index page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have written an ASP.NET application that users access to check fields off. Instead of the user having to go into the edit page and hitting save, I want them to be able to just check it off on the index page and it either saves automatically or they can click the save button on the index page. I have made the fields EditorFor instead of Display for, and added the save button to the page. However, I am not sure how to implement the code to save in the controller.

Here is the code I have been trying out on my viewcontroller, but it says "does not contain a definition for save"

```
public virtual ActionResult Save(Doctor model)
      {

          Doctor.Save();            

      }
```

Comment: What does it save? Where does it save? How do you save?

Comment: It is just going to save the fields that changed on the index page. And they are just check box fields. I took the HTML from the edit page and put it on the index page, but it doesn't do anything when I click it and can't find where the code is that executes when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Save() on class Doctor which means there must be a static method in Doctor class. If it is not static but it does existing in the Doctor class then call the save method by model.Save().

If you are using EF then make sure inside the Save() method you're attaching the updated values on model object to respective EF entity or adding the object to the context in case new item is being created.

Answer (score 0):

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Doctor", FormMethod.Post))
    {


        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Foo):
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Foo)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Foo)
        </p>

        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.barImage)
            <input type="file" name="Image" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />

        </p>
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Doctor doc)
{
  your_dbcontext db = new your_dbcontext();
  db.Add<Doctor>(doc);
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have a question if you don't mind, why is it ActionResult Create()? I was thinking it would be edit.

Comment: I just edited some of my own code and forgot to change it to Save. (to be clear, its just the name of the actionresult)

Comment: Ok, I see. So I changed it to save, should I also change it to     db.Save<Doctor>(doc); ?

Comment: No this is the command that tells your dbcontext to save it to the database